# Modular Reduction in the Ring $\mathbb{Z}_{q}[x]/(x^n + 1)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

May someone please explain how the reduction is done? I am familiar with other algebraic structures but wondering if I am doing reduction correctly for this.

It is understood that a Polynomial Ring of this form, $\mathbb{Z}_{q}[x]/(x^n + 1)$, consists of the set of all polynomials defined by $(x^n + 1)$ with coefficients over $\mathbb{Z}_q = \{0, 1, ..., q-1\}$.

For simplicity, say I am working in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]/[x^4+1]$

Say I multiply two polynomials in the ring according to the convolution formula.

[image]

```
    3      2      1   0 <-- coefficient indecis
```

$a(x) = 4x^3 + 1x^2 + 1x + 2$

$b(x) = 1x^3 + 1x^2 + 3x + 2$

$n=4, n-1=3$

all coefficient arithmetic is done mod 5
add like terms and reduce mod 5
negative numbers, we add multiples of mod 5

$$a(x)\cdot b(x) = ([(a_0b_1x + a_0b_2x^2 + a_0b_3x^3) + (a_1b_2x^3 + a_1b_3x^4 + a_2b_3x^3)]  - \\
        [a_3b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_2x + a_1b_3 + a_2b_3x + a_3b_3x^2]) \mod (x^4 + 1)\\
      =[(x + 2x^2 + x^3) + (x^3 + x^4 + x^3)] - [(2 + 1 + 4x + 1 + 1x + 4x^2)] \mod.. \\
      = [x^4 + 3x^3 + 2x^2 + x] - [4x^2 + 4] \mod..\\
      = [x^4 + 3x^3 + (2-4)x^2 + x - 4] \mod..\\
      = [x^4 + 3x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 1] \mod (x^4 + 1) 
$$

Three questions:

1. convolution formula is correct.
2. subtraction is like normal polynomials: $4x^2 - x^2 = 3x^2$
3. reduction: done like standard polynomial division to obtain residue

Given $(x^4 + 3x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 1) \mod (x^4 + 1)$:
$\Rightarrow (x^4 + 3x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 1) / (x^4 + 1)$
first subtraction:
$\Rightarrow (x^4 + 3x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 1) - (x^4 + 1) = 3x^3 + 3x^2 + x$ (final answer)

Given $(3x^5 + x^3 + 1) \mod (x^4 + 1) 
\Rightarrow (3x^5 + x^3 + 1) / 3x(x^4 + 1)$
first subtraction:
$\Rightarrow (3x^5 + x^3 + 1) - (3x^5 + 3x) = x^3 - 3x + 1)$

Answer (score 3):

> convolution formula is correct.

No, it is not correct; if $a = x^0$ and $b = x^0$, your formula would give $a \cdot b = 0$, which is obviously wrong.

The textbook way to express the multiplication operation is:

$$a \cdot b = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_i \cdot b_j \cdot x^{i+j} \pmod{x^n+1}$$

An equivalent way (easily seen by the identity $x^{k+n} \equiv -x^k \pmod{x^n+1}$ for any $k$) is

$$a \cdot b = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1-i} a_i \cdot b_j \cdot x^{i+j} - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=n-i}^{n-1} a_i \cdot b_j \cdot x^{i+j-n}$$

I believe the latter is what you intended

> subtraction is like normal polynomials: $4x^2−x^2=3x^2$

Yes (with the caveat that, as you yourself mentioned, the operations in the coefficients is done $\mod p$, in your example, $\mod 5$)

> reduction: done like standard polynomial division to obtain residue

It can be done that way; it is likely more efficient to take advantage of the identity I mentioned above, that $x^{k+n} \equiv -x^k \pmod{ x^n+1 }$)

Comment: I took the formula provided from a PhD thesis. Searched it up on several university lectures and articles, none provided explicit formula with indecis. Some even listes this for the coefficients: $$c_i = {\sum_{j+k=i} a_j \cdot b_k - \sum_{j+k=n+i} a_j \cdot b_k }\pmod{q}$$ for coefficients of degree at most n-1. However, for the formula provided, when both polynomials have degree 0, the outer loop/sum conditions are not met and we never enter them. Thank you so much for the formulas you provided Poncho, I tried them out and get the same result for both. :)